# Python ElementTree search for number inside range in XML

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a huge XML file that crashes in Notepad++ when I try to search for anything. I'm trying to parse it in Python 3.8 using ElementTree. I have no experience with parsing XML files; I looked at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), but I am still not sure where to start for my particular need.

Specifically, I want to search for a number within the index as highlighted in Line25 of the screenshot; for example, I want to search for "3" and then get the previous line's "rate" returned and the current line's "depth" returned. But I would also want the same information for other ranges that include "3" like in Line21.

There is only one `root.tag` which is at the top of the screenshot. The "children" are all called `Source` and don't have have any attributes.

I haven't made it any farther than `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` and `root = ET.parse(filein).getroot()` in the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc

doc = SimplifiedDoc()
doc.loadFile('test.xml', lineByline=True)
for src in doc.getIterable('Source'):
  if src.outerHtml.find('3')>0:
    print (src.IncrementalMfd.rate)
    print (src.Geometry.depth)
```